# how to switch from h2 embedded to server mode

Tags: database, spring-boot, rest, automated-tests, jhipster

I have a jhipster gateway which starts an embedded h2 console (only accessible from inside), this gateway runs inside a docker on a server we use for testing purposes.
I generated an empty cypress project which will test the ui which is deployed and makes requests through my gateway to other services.

I generated another spring boot application, which will make api calls which directly saves/deletes/gets/edits data in my db.

This application will be used in order for cypress to make requests and test the db at the same time.

the steps would be like this:
Cypress Tests and the needed rest calls will be written locally if everything works, it will be pushed.
After pushing with a pipe my tests will be running and testing my deployed ui.

My problem starts at the local testing, my api can not access my h2 db fom gateway because it is inside it and not open for other apps, it would be possible if they were inside the same docker, but this is not the case and locally I do not want to use docker.

I read here: https://jsoftbiz.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/share-an-h2-in-memory-database-among-several-jvms/
that h2 can run as a server accessable from other applications. I tried to adding the config inside there to my h2.server.properties inside gateway, but it still started embedded.

My question know if there is another way to configure my h2 db to be accessable from outside?

this would have the benefit of having one testing db instead each for local and server.

Answer (score 0):

JHipster already does it for you.

Have a look at `DatabaseConfiguration` class, it's in `h2TCPServer()` method. It finds an available port to listen to and logs it, usually it's the http port + 10000, see in `getValidPortForH2()` method.

So H2 is embedded but can be accessed by external applications like DBeaver for instance.

The external [JDBC URL](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url) should be something like this:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:<port>/<database name>:<application name>;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Be aware that it's only for `dev` profile because it's not secure.

Comment: hi,
I get the following error when I try to connect to my db:
A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:18088/gateway:gateway;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;FORBID_CREATION=TRUE". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-200] 90011/90011 (Help)

Comment: Are you using h2 file storage or in mem? Check the H2 doc http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url for all possibilities.

Comment: I can connect via this so I guess file:
jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/gateway

Comment: is that a problem for the servermode, that I am using file storage?

Comment: no it just means that url could be different from what I posted because I use mem, try the different possibilities in the h2 doc I linked.

Comment: I am getting this error nearly with every try;
Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt (Connection refused): localhost" [90067-200] 90067/90067 
Or this one:
not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149 (Help)

Comment: I don't have time now, try to run under debugger and see what h2 checks